# javascript to switch class of this element and others

Tags: javascript, css

Hi,

I have this html code for 2 switch buttons. When you press one the pressed one changes classes so it will look pressed but it will also have the other one change classes too so it will look unpressed. This way there will always be a pressed button and unpressed one.

```
<span id="but1" class="pressed" onclick="myswitcher(but2);">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="myswitcher(but1);">BUTTON 2</span>
```

This is my javascript

```
  function myswitcher(elem) {
  if (this.classList.contains("notpressed"))
    elem.classList.add("notpressed");
    elem.classList.remove("pressed");
    this.classList.add("pressed");
    this.classList.remove("notpressed");
}
```

its not working. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: you cannot use switch as function name. It is reserved word.

Comment: okay, I changed it but it still wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove the class for existing pressed button and add to the button which we have just clicked.

It can be achieved simply by core JavaScript as follows:

```js
function toggleClass(ev){
  var el = document.querySelector(".pressed");
  el.className = 'notpressed';
  ev.target.className = 'pressed';
}
```

```css
span{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #FCFCFC;
}
.notpressed{
  background:#CCC;
}
.pressed{
  background: #DFF789;
}
```

```html
<span id="but1" class="pressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="toggleClass(event);">BUTTON 2</span>
```

Comment: it looks great. One question: the javascript codes needs to be put along with the html code or can be loaded externally from a js file?

Comment: Yes, it can be loaded externally from js file, it’s simple JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code i created.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('span');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
 button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if (!button.classList.contains('pressed')) {
     // unpress all pressed button
      let pressed = document.querySelectorAll('span.button.pressed');
      pressed.forEach((p) => {
       p.classList.remove('pressed');
      })
      // press the clicked button
     button.classList.add('pressed');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
span.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: red;
}

span.button.pressed {
  background-color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<span class="button pressed">BUTTON 1</span>
<span class="button" >BUTTON 2</span>
<span class="button">BUTTON 3</span>
<span class="button" >BUTTON 4</span>
```

Comment: It works fine but then it means I was totally off with my code?

Comment: on your code you passed "but1" and "but2", the ids of the button, just the ids. And then inside your function you didn't select the element with that id.

Your code would work, but with that function, you're gonna have to pass other buttons to your function to unpress them. what if you have 50 buttons

Comment: Its supposed to be elem which is the Id of the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is reserved keyword in javascript. That cannot be used. Beside there need to change the logic of your implementation.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to find the button which have the class pressed, then loop through it to remove the class and also you need to pass the context that is `this` in the function call.

```js
function switchClass(elem) {
 // get the collection of all the elements which have .pressed 
  var getPressed = document.querySelectorAll('.pressed');
  // then remove the class from it 
  if (getPressed.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < getPressed.length; i++) {
      getPressed[i].classList.remove('pressed')
    }
  }
   // add the class on the element which have triggered the event
  elem.classList.add('pressed');

}
```

```css
.pressed {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.notpressed {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<span id="but1" class="notpressed" onclick="switchClass(this);">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="switchClass(this);">BUTTON 2</span>
```

Comment: Great code but why there is no indication to remove or add notpressed class and it still works?

Comment: `elem.classList.add('pressed');` this will add class & `getPressed[i].classList.remove('pressed')` will remove class

Comment: But what about the notpressed class? I need to remove that from the element. It cant have both.

Comment: @CainNuke initially those class are added in the DOM, when the user have not pressed and button , by default it will have `notpressed` class

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here.

1. `this` refers to the function, not any element.
2. You're not selecting the element by the ID you're passing in.
3. `if` statements require braces if there's more than one statement.

Here's your corrected code.

```js
function myswitcher(clicked, other) {
  other = document.getElementById(other); // need to get the element, not just the string

  if (clicked.classList.contains("notpressed")) {
    other.classList.add("notpressed");
    other.classList.remove("pressed");
    clicked.classList.add("pressed");
    clicked.classList.remove("notpressed");
  }
}
```

```css
.pressed {
  background: green;
}
.notpressed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="but1" class="pressed" onclick="myswitcher(this, 'but2');">BUTTON 1</span>
<span id="but2" class="notpressed" onclick="myswitcher(this, 'but1');">BUTTON 2</span>
```

(pressed is green, notpressed is red)

`this` in the HTML refers to the element that is being clicked, while the second parameter is the other element's ID.

Comment: do you mind to include the run snipped button? Its not working on my end.

Comment: Whoops, made a small error in the if statement. I've just edited it, and will add a snippet in a moment

Comment: @CainNuke As a side note, since you're initializing the elements with classes, you're also able to just use `toggle` instead of `add` and `remove`.

Comment: thank you. It works great here but not on my actual code. Im using firefox. Is there anyway to debug it and see whats causing it not to work?

Comment: What version of Firefox? I am on FF57/Quantum. Please remember that we can't help you debug something you didn't post - that's why it's supposed to be a MVCE (the 'C' stands for complete).

Comment: Same version here. I mean with something like inspect element from the webdev tools.

Comment: You could certainly inspect if from devtools. It would be great if you could update the original post with full details, though.

Comment: but I see the console and I see no error there so I dont know whats going on.

Comment: I don't know where to look, as I don't know what your code is like. You *do not* have to post pages of code, as it should be the minimum required to replicate the issue. Unless you're willing to put in the effort to cut the code down to the minimum and update your post, there's no way I can help you. I did what was asked in your original post, as is evidenced by the snippet.

Comment: I see. Thank you anyway for your kind help.